# How to make the _make_train_function of TF1.15 similar as make_train_function of TF2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow1.15

In Keras with **tensorflow 2** I can override the *make_train_function*() function (when creating a custom model for instance) and I can set the force parameter to true. This allows me to dynamically call a function (the random function in my code, just as a test) and adds its return value to the loss at each batch

Problem: I am not using **tensorflow 1.15** and the only function that exists and that is similar to make_train_function() is in keras/engine/training.py :

```
def _make_train_function(self):
    if not hasattr(self, 'train_function'):
        raise RuntimeError('You must compile your model before using it.')
    self._check_trainable_weights_consistency()

    #if self.train_function is None:

    inputs = (self._feed_inputs +
                self._feed_targets +
                self._feed_sample_weights)
    if self._uses_dynamic_learning_phase():
        inputs += [K.learning_phase()]
    # rrr = float(random.randrange(1, 1000000, 100000)) SOME RANDOM number (very small or very big)
    with K.name_scope('training'):
        with K.name_scope(self.optimizer.__class__.__name__):
            training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(
                params=self._collected_trainable_weights,
                loss=self.total_loss+rrr)
        updates = (self.updates +
                    training_updates +
                    self.metrics_updates)
        # Gets loss and metrics. Updates weights at each call.
        self.train_function = K.function(
            inputs,
            [self.total_loss+rrr] + self.metrics_tensors,
            updates=updates,
            name='train_function',
            **self._function_kwargs)
```

I have tried to modify this function by removing the different conditions (if, with) but still not working. So is there a way to modify this function such that it takes into account the same “force” argument that exists for the *make_train_function* of TF2 ?

Thanks a lot

p.s: a proof of work would be that the rrr variable is really updated on each batch